# Change color of expressions that starts with '@'

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I need to create a winform to color expressions that starts with '@' that the user wrote in a textbox (can be a richTextBox or some Infragistics tool, does't really  matter, it just have to work).

Exemple:

*nothing @expression nothingelse*

the *@expression* must be colored

I've tried to split the string from the textbox by the spaces to identify the word, but I wasn't abble to replace it correctly. Now I'm learning about Regex and trying to apply it to my problem.

I'm using C# in Visual Studio Community 2017.

**EDIT**

I changed a little the code from [here](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268162/colorir-palavra-at%C3%A9-um-limitador), trying to fit it into my problem. But the limiter doesnt work as it is suppouse to. I belive that it is happening becouse that the selection starts in the '@', but there can be a space before that, so the code doesn't work.

Here is the code as I'm using it:

```
private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int current = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox1.Lines.Length; i++)
    {
        string line = richTextBox1.Lines[i];

        int index = line.IndexOf(' '), lineFirstIndex = line.IndexOf('@');

        if (index != -1 && lineFirstIndex != -1)
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(lineFirstIndex, index);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            lineFirstIndex = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i);

            richTextBox1.Select(lineFirstIndex, line.Length);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Empty;

        }
    }
    richTextBox1.Select(current, 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this for 2 hole days. I've tried to split the string from the textbox by the spaces to identify the word, but I wasn't abble to replace it correctly. Now I'm learning about Regex and trying to apply it to my problem.

Comment: Code in the edt

Comment: I've posted [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352623/how-to-color-different-words-with-different-colors-in-a-richtextbox-while-a-user/48358496#48358496) a few days ago. Give it a look. It seems pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Regex like this :

```
foreach (string result in Regex.Split(TextBox1, @" @\w+")) 
{
  //do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the result that I wished, but there is a little problem. If i erase something with BackSpace, the backcolor starts to highlight everything.

I belive that this is something of the SelectionBackColor propriety, becouse it doesn't happend when I'm using SelectionColor.

The code:

```
 private void FindAt() //acha arrobas
    {
        for(int r = 0; r <= tam; r++)
        {
            for(int z = 0; z < (tam - r); z++)
            {
                if (z > 8) break;

                String temp = text.Substring(r, z);
                char aux = '\0';

                if (lista.FindStringExact(temp) != -1)
                {
                    if (tam > r + z) aux = text.ElementAt(r + z);
                    if ((r > 0 && text.ElementAt(r - 1) == '@') && aux == ' ')
                    {
                        atIndex[0, ctrlAt] = r-1;   //salva posição inicial da variavel, incluindo o @ (por isso o -1)
                        atIndex[1, ctrlAt] = z + 1;   //salva comprimento da variavel, + 1 por causa do @ (segundo argumento da substring)
                        ctrlAt++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the function to color the substring:

```
private void ColorAt() //colore variaveis
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < ctrlAt; a++)
        {
            if (atIndex[0, a] != -1)
            {
                richTextBox1.Select(atIndex[0, a], atIndex[1, a]);
                richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
        }
    }
```