# Changing richtextbox text color without .selectioncolor?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, highlighting

i have a keyup event where by it will highlight any words that are incorrectly spelt however i need to change all the text to the normal color before applying the changes.

i can do this using `rtbEditor.SelectionColor = Color.Black` however this generates flicker when the user is typing (due to the `.select`).

is there anyway i can disable the highlight temporarily or change the all the text color without `.select`.

i have tried to find this online but my request/question is more specific than the ones i have found online.

Comment: See whether the core of your question could be similar to what [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352623/how-to-color-different-words-with-different-colors-in-a-richtextbox-while-a-user?answertab=active#tab-top) is performing. If it is, it can be easily translated to vb.net.

Comment: Hi Jimi thank you for the reply, however i have already done that bit its not that bit i have a problem with, its the constant refresh after each key press, because the user may change the spelling causing the word to be still highlighted in red. even though they have corrected it. so to refresh it i select all text and change to black and run the changetext to red function i have. this is what is giving me my flicker. the select all text and change to black. i have already got my spelling mistakes highlighted.

Comment: Yes, that's why I thought it could be what you're looking for. The code I linked (which I just tweaked a little), colors words only if those words are contained in a list. If they're not, the words are left untouched (or re-colored if it's the case) using the default ForeColor. There's no visible flickering, because just one word is selected, if necessary. If you want, I can translate it to vb.net so you can try it out.

Comment: ahhh i know what you mean now! yes put them into a list so i dont need to refresh all the text. thank you.

Comment: YES! And for more than one reason. If you use LINQ for the lookups, its queries are cached. Specifically, a `.Select.Where`, the first time is used, may take [N] millisenconds. The subsequent queries, even if the List changes, take 1 to 7 TICKS to complete.

Comment: thats how fast i want it :) thanks i will have a look. if you want to put a proper answer il tick it. dan

Comment: Well, I'll see if I can come up with something meaningful to say.

Comment: I just posted another answer about this matter. It's in C#, but I can be easily translated in VB.net. It shows how to keep track of a user edit when a previously selected (colored) word is changed or a new one is added. It doesn't use Linq to track the current word, but this also can be adapted. See if can be useful (well, if you haven't found your solution yet).