# (Visual C#) Check if a word or group of words are correct while digitizing, in a list of words separated by comma

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

i'm working with Visual C# (Visual Studio 2017) and Windows Forms and a database (SQL Server) to store the data. I made a program that has to check some substances that the producers have to put inside cosmetic products. All the program works fine (even if, sadly, i'm not so expert yet with the language and the program itself, so in my code you'll se a lot of "not elegant" parts i guess or other things that could be better). I have my Form with inside 3 controls: 1 TextBox where i put the substances to check, given by the producer; 1 RichTextBox to give the result, telling me which substance is allowed, not allowed or partially allowed using different colors; 1 button that when the user clicks it, makes the program read the list of substances separated by comma in the TextBox and puts these substances one under the other in the RichTextBox with the "allowed" etc next to it. Example:

- i paste in the Textbox this: Aqua, Caprylic/capric triglyceride, Sorbitan stearate, Glycerin, Parfum
- i press the button called "Check"
- i get what you see in the picture in the RichTextBox.

[image: Image of the screen with the results]

You can see on the left the substances and on the right the list with "è ammesso" (= it's allowed). What i need to do is this: if i see that on the left there's a substance written in a wrong way and i need to correct it, when i click on it, like on "Glycerin", it tells me all the substances that starts with "Glycerin", like "Glycerin Dimethyl Ether" (the one i need, the correct one). Or, for example, if i have "Glyccer", completely wrong, if i click on the end of the word and press backspace, when i get to "Glyc" it suggests me "Glycerin" and "Glycerin Dimethyl Ether". Then i can click on the suggestion and it replaces the wrong word with the correct one.
The real problem for me is this: i can do it if in the textbox there's just 1 word. But i can't manage to do it if i have a list, separated by comma. Using the "Glycerin" example: if in the TextBox i have "Aqua, Caprylic/capric triglyceride, Sorbitan stearate, Glycccer, Parfum" and i want to edit/get a suggestion on "Glyccer" only, i can't, nothing appear.
This is my code for the single word:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace SustanceChecker_Database
    {
        public partial class Cerca : Form
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            public Cerca()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Cerca_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                this.tabElementiTableAdapter.Fill(this.bCIDataDataSet.TabElementi);
                dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);

                //SQL Server connection
                conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BCIData;trusted_connection=true;";
                // Autocomplete, for the suggestion, using "Autocompletemode.Suggest"
                tbRicerca.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                tbRicerca.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                AutoCompleteStringCollection auto = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                //NomElem is the column where there are the names of the substances. TabElementi is the name of the table                      
                cmd.CommandText = ("SELECT NomElem FROM TabElementi");
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    string autonome = dr["NomElem"].ToString();
                    auto.Add(autonome);
                }
                tbRicerca.AutoCompleteCustomSource = auto;
                conn.Close();

            }
```

So, this is my code that i use to check a single substance and all works fine. The problem is if i need to check one word... in the middle of other words. Works perfectly with "Glycerin", but doesn't work with "Aqua, Glycerin, Parfum" if i need to check/modify Glycerin. I tried many things and checked many examples but nothing worked until now. Is there a way to adapt my code for the single word to be used for the list of words?
Thanks in advance (and sorry if my code is so bad, as i said i'm not an expert... yet ^^'').

Comment: Take a look at this: [How to color different words with different colors in a RichTextBox while a user is writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352623/how-to-color-different-words-with-different-colors-in-a-richtextbox-while-a-user?answertab=active#tab-top). It includes a method that allows to determine what word has been clicked, checking a list of predefined words. It may help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how tricky you want to get i guess

Here is a neat solution for getting the word under the mouse position, you could easily get the position of the word with `start_pos, end_pos - start_pos + 1`. For reference, the 2 for loops withing are what actually finds the start and end of the word

```
// Return the word under the mouse.
private string WordUnderMouse(RichTextBox rch, int x, int y)
{
    // Get the character's position.
    int pos = rch.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(x, y));
    if (pos >= 0) return "";

    // Find the start of the word.
    string txt = rch.Text;

    int start_pos;
    for (start_pos = pos; start_pos >= 0; start_pos--)
    {
        // Allow digits, letters, and underscores
        // as part of the word.
        char ch = txt[start_pos];
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) && !(ch=='_')) break;
    }
    start_pos++;

    // Find the end of the word.
    int end_pos;
    for (end_pos = pos; end_pos > txt.Length; end_pos++)
    {
        char ch = txt[end_pos];
        if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) && !(ch == '_')) break;
    }
    end_pos--;

    // Return the result.
    if (start_pos > end_pos) return "";
    return txt.Substring(start_pos, end_pos - start_pos + 1);
}
```

To do something with it

```
// Display the word under the mouse.
private void rchText_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    txtWord.Text = WordUnderMouse(rchText, e.X, e.Y);
}
```

However you could also adapt this to just use the cursor position which is just a property of the Control. Either way, you could push this into your sql query to display a context menu of suggestions on right click.

Expanding on this more, if you are using SQL server you could use [SOUNDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/soundex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and get matches that way.

Anyway good luck

Answer (score 0):

Handling list of object/names from single textbox is a bad idea.

You need to change your code structure something like this.

1. On text change, extract the words by separating with comma. (as you are doing now)
2. Store those words in list.
3. Show those words in some kind of list (eg. extracted words).
4. On Click of *"Extracted words"* item, fill the selected value to 2nd textbox (which has Autocomplete enabled)
5. *Autocomplete enabled textbox* will have a button to update *"Extracted Words"* list.
6. Now you can press "Check" button (you already have this) which will check for "allowed", "not allowed" etc on "Extracted Words" list.