# Adding multiple non url Hyperlinks in RichTextBox C# to throw an event for each

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, adventure

Starting with the context... I am making a game Text Adventure game using C# Windows Form because I am a beginner and it is what I understand. (I do not want to use something like Inform, this is a project so I can learn.)

That being said, I would like to avoid using buttons and most of the content will be displayed in a richtextbox. I have looked around and I can't find anything that suits my needs. (Yes I have looked here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox but it doesn't handle multiple links well and it has other issues. )

My aim would basically be to use the links in the richtextbox as a navigation menu and for contextual purpose. I would like to be able to have text before and after the link, like if it was incorporated in the text itself.

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Room1 Room1 = new Room1();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PlayArea.Text = "Welcome to the Game! Would you like to start?";
        Game();
    }
    private void Game()
    {
        PlayArea.Text = "Welcome Back!";
        button1.Text = "Start?";
        button1.Click += Button1_Beginning;
        void Button1_Beginning(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Click -= Button1_Beginning;
            FirstRoom();
        }
    }
    private void FirstRoom()
    {
        PlayArea.Text = Room1.Description;
        button1.Text = "ClickMe!";
        button1.Click += Button1_FirstRoom;
        void Button1_FirstRoom(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlayArea.Text = String.Empty;
        }
        button2.Text = "Return";
        button2.Click += Button2_FirstRoom;
        void Button2_FirstRoom(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Click -= Button1_FirstRoom;
            button2.Click -= Button2_FirstRoom;
            ClearButtonText();
            Game();
        }
    }
    private void ClearButtonText()
    {
        foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        {
            button.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

For now, some things are activated by buttons, my goal is to remove that and have most things activated by hyperlinks.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you thought about just using labels with click events?

Comment: I have, but labels are very hard to place. It was the first thing I tried but the formatting get weird and I am not sure how to put things after. I'd like something more versatile.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I deleted that comment because I realized after posting it that it could get somewhat complicated and would require some explanation. A simple example on how to detect a colored word and act on it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352623/how-to-color-different-words-with-different-colors-in-a-richtextbox-while-a-user?answertab=active#tab-top). Can be combined with a mouse pointer change to have a better *link effect*. -- Or, you could use the Auto hyperlink detection feature of the RTB, combining it with RTF formatted text to create non-Web links.

Comment: Or, go WPF and use a Flow Document: [Flow Document Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/flow-document-overview)