# How to change forecolor of textbox from specific word?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a below code to change the forecolor of text after the '@' symbol but in my textbox I can have two or more '@' symbols what can I do to make all text red after the first '@' symbol? In my situation my textbox color change until the second '@' symbol. Here is my code ;

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count>0)
            {
                ListViewItem item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];

                richTextBox1.Text = item.SubItems[0].Text + " @ ";

                string splitted = richTextBox1.Text.Split('@')[1];
                int col = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(splitted);
                int length = splitted.Length;
                richTextBox1.Select(col, length);
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            }       
        }
```

**It is also fine for me if I can write sentences to newline after the '@' symbol.**

Comment: [How to color different words with different colors in a RichTextBox while a user is writing and raise an event when that colored text is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48358496/7444103)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this will be really helpful for me.