# Click and recognize part of text in textbox vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net, textbox, mouseover

I am trying to make a program that utilises a textbox that has text options listed in it that can be clicked on.

As a textbox example:

[Selection:<1><2><3>]

so the user could then as example click on (over the text) `<2>` to select the 2nd option or `<3>` so select the 3rd option. The idea comes from the `AutoCAD` commands prompt which uses a similar system.

How would I achieve something like this in vb.net code (if its even possible)?

Comment: [How to color different words with different colors in a RichTextBox while a user is writing and raise an event when that colored text is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48358496/7444103) -- You only need the mouse click handling part (first and last snippet +  the class object).

Comment: That's an awful lot of work to reproduce what a [LinkLabel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/linklabel-control-overview-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) can already do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
    Dim SplitText As String() = TextBox1.Text.Split(CChar("<"), ">")
    Dim SelectedText As String = GetSelectedText()
    Dim Options As New List(Of String)

    If Not SelectedText = "" Then
        For i = 0 To SplitText.Length - 1
            If IsNumeric(SplitText(i)) Then
                Options.Add("<" & SplitText(i) & ">")
            End If
        Next
        For i = 0 To Options.Count - 1
            If SelectedText = Options(i) Then
                'Put your code here if it is the current option in the loop equals the selected option.
                'I added a messagebox just so you can see the current option.
                MessageBox.Show("You selected option: " & Options(i))
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetSelectedText()
    Dim CursorPosition As Integer = TextBox1.SelectionStart
    Dim SelectedNumber As String = ""
    Dim NumberLength As Integer = 0

    If CursorPosition = 0 Or CursorPosition = TextBox1.Text.Length Then
        Return ""
    End If
    Do Until Mid(TextBox1.Text, CursorPosition - NumberLength, 1) = "<"
        NumberLength += 1
    Loop
    SelectedNumber = Mid(TextBox1.Text, CursorPosition - NumberLength, NumberLength + 1)
    NumberLength = 0
    CursorPosition += 1
    Do Until Mid(TextBox1.Text, CursorPosition + NumberLength, 1) = ">"
        NumberLength += 1
    Loop
    SelectedNumber &= Mid(TextBox1.Text, CursorPosition, NumberLength + 1)

    If IsNumeric(SelectedNumber.Remove(0, 1).Remove(SelectedNumber.Length - 2, 1)) Then
        Return SelectedNumber
    Else
        Return ""
    End If
End Function
```

I put this inside of the textbox click event, and it works. I did not try putting the code in any other events. I assume that the textbox is named: `TextBox1`.

Comment: This works but it requiers me to still manually highlight the text first... I]m working on it now

Comment: @LabRat, I have updated my code. Now when you click on the textbox it will find which number you clicked on instead of having to select it.

Comment: This works perfectly, though i now need to figure out how this code works so I don't just coppy and past but also understand it though I will manage to understand it eventually :)

Comment: @LabRat I fixed a bug that I found. I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example showing how to build a "menu" with a [LinkLabel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/linklabel-control-overview-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private menuItems() As String = {"cat", "dog", "fish"}

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim menu As String = "Selection: " & String.Join(", ", menuItems)
        LinkLabel1.Text = menu
        LinkLabel1.Links.Clear()
        For Each item In menuItems
            LinkLabel1.Links.Add(menu.IndexOf(item), item.Length)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub LinkLabel1_LinkClicked(sender As Object, e As LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs) Handles LinkLabel1.LinkClicked
        Dim i As Integer = LinkLabel1.Links.IndexOf(e.Link)
        Label1.Text = menuItems(i)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Output:

[image]